# Redirect last action's stdout using >>= in haskell

Tags: haskell, pipe

How can i get the output from previous action and print it using `>>=` in haskell?

In shell, it is like,

```
echo "hello world" | { read test; echo test=$test; }
```

In haskell, i am looking for something like,

```
putStrLn "hello world" >>= {x <- getArgs; print x}
```

getArgs stdin must take its input from putStrLn's stdout.

Edit#1,
Alexey &  aochagavia, thanks for your inputs. This works.

```
x :: IO String
x = return "hello world"

main = do
  x >>= print
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Check the type signature of `return`: `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`. Maybe you could take a look at http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output

Comment: removed the `return`... but still errors and am debugging it

Comment: You can go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83002/haskell-room to discuss it in the chat

Comment: `getArgs` does not read from stdin.

Comment: thanks sepp2k.. din't know, that getArgs is for process arguments...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, `>>=` doesn't have anything to do with stdout. You can use `capture_` function from the [silently](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/silently) package:

```
 do x <- capture_ (putStrLn "hello world")
    print x
```

or just `capture_ (putStrLn "hello world") >>= print`.